# Is it safe to have the AWSAccessKeyId in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services

I'm using aws-sdk to create a download link for a file from my s3 bucket

**controller**

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new(
  access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
  secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_KEY"]
)
bucket = s3.buckets['my_bucket']
object = bucket.objects["path/to/file.zip"]
@link_url = object.url_for(:get, { :expires => 20.minutes.from_now, :secure => true })
```

**view**

```
<%= link_to "Download", @link_url %>
```

When I mouse over the link I can see my access_key_id in the url.  Is this safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID is public and required for matching the URL signature. But AWS_SECRET_KEY is private.